# Ms Access, make one table get data from another table in real time

Tags: ms-access, vba

So, i have 2 tables, let's say : Customers and Activity. Customers containing only customers and activity containing customers but also other pieces of information.

I have a form to write data in the Customers table. 
What i need is the Activity table to auto-update itself each time I write an entry in the Customers table.

Is it possible to create a relationship between the two tables to do that? Or should I write something at the end of the code I use for the form?
Is it possible for instance to create a function that i call at the end of the code i use for the form?
Thanks.

Comment: In Access you would need to use a form on the first table and then put your code in the appropriate locations in that form ie. After_Update Before_Delete etc.

Comment: If you are using Access 2010 or newer you might be able to use an event-driven [data macro](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200?CorrelationId=fd1e6868-51a4-4cc3-88be-4cb5add8d666&ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA) to some advantage.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to automatically update, independently of any form, a table based on changes made to another table, I would recommend a data macro which is new to MS Access 2010. They're pretty cool and are similar to triggers in enterprise level relational database management systems.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Activity table. Under table tools create a named macro called NewRecord. Create a parameter called prmCustomer. Your macro could look like this:

```
Create a Record In Activity
    Alias 
SetField
    Name Customer
    Value = [prmCustomer]
```

Then open your Customer table. Under table tools create an After Insert Event. Your event could look like this:

```
RunDataMacro
    Macro Name Activity.NewRecord
Parameters
    prmCustomer = CustomerID
```

You'll have to do some playing around since you haven't given much info, but that's the gist of it.